# ESRI File Geodatabase - Trying to use CURRENT TIME in Definition Query

Tags: esri-geodatabase, sql, definition-query

Is it me, or are the date functions in the file geodatabase a total nightmare.

Anyway, I am trying to set up a fairly simple definition query that contains a subquery with a date comparison.  My definition query looks like this:

```
"OBJECTID" IN (SELECT "assetid" from dummydata WHERE "restoretime" < CURRENT_TIME)
```

According the [ESRI SQL Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm), the current time function is defined as CURRENT TIME (no underscore) but that breaks the definition query altogether.  With the underscore, I dont get any errors, but the selection set is always null.  Every row in dummydata has a restoretime value set which is definitely older than the current time.
What am I doing wrong here?

FYI - ArcMap 10 SP4

UPDATE: Some sample rows from the dummydata table

```
OID     assetid     outagetime               restoretime
1            1      5/10/2012 3:06:59 PM     5/10/2012 3:07:04 PM
2            2      5/10/2012 3:06:59 PM     5/10/2012 3:09:14 PM
```

Comment: Are you sure that your restoretime field actually contains time information and not just the date? Will your query work if you replace CURRENT_TIME with CURRENT_DATE? Are your sure that your FGDB is of v10 flavor as it seems that the CURRENT_TIME function is new as of v10 as it is not mentioned in the 9.3 documentation - http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL_reference

Answer (score 3):

Since the field you are basing your definition query on contains both date and time, you cannot just use the "CURRENT_TIME" function as the comparison.  You have to use a function that compares both date and time.  The ArcGIS desktop help states that queries use standard SQL syntax:  [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm)

If you look at the [SQL.org](http://www.sql.org) website for [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/functions-datetime.html), you see a reference for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Here are what the different functions return:
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:  Complete date and time expression:  2001-12-23 14:39:53
Current_TIME:  Current Time:  14:39:53
Current_DATE:  Current Date:  2001-12-23
Section 6.8.4 of that page specifically discusses the [Current Date/Time functions](http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

So your expression should probably look something like this:

```
"OBJECTID" IN (SELECT "assetid" from dummydata WHERE "restoretime" < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The one thing you want to ensure is that the field you are querying against is defined as a date/time field, or else the comparison won't work.  From the look of the sample data you included, it probably is, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the response.  however, it looks the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not available until 10.1 - http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/48393-How-to-get-current-timestamp-in-where-clause

Comment: so is there any solutions to comparing date in 10.0?